# loading arabic language data by JSON url in swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

`

```
    var Cities:[String] = [String]()
    let requestURL =  "https://----".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!

    //Sending http post request
    Alamofire.request(requestURL).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let swiftyJsonVar1 = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
            let strjson = swiftyJsonVar1.rawString()!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(strjson)
                if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["Cities"].arrayObject {
                    print(swiftyJsonVar["Cities"].arrayObject! )
                    for a in resData {
                        let v = a as! [String:Any]
                        let City = v["Name"]!
                        Cities.append(City as! String)
                    }
                    self.TFrom.filterStrings(Cities) // put data from array to Component AutoComplete
                    self.TFrom.startVisible = true
                    self.TFrom.maxNumberOfResults = 5
                    self.TTo.filterStrings(Cities) // put data from array to Component AutoComplete
                    self.TTo.startVisible = true
                    self.TTo.maxNumberOfResults = 5

                }
            }
    }
```

`
when using JSON url has English data, that is fine but in Arabic return empty, any help?
[swift code to show data in url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIhKU.png)

Comment: Copy/paste code, don't post screenshot.

Comment: Do you check if arabic data returned correctly from API using postman?

Comment: @MoayadAlkouz yes, it's fine

Comment: @Yasmin and the response is JSON or String?

Comment: @MoayadAlkouz JSON

Comment: post your code here not in image. and debug it does your Service json giving arabic. it should have some kind of text if not exact arabic.

Comment: Please put your code at question not screen shot, also try to print or debug the swiftyJsonVar1

Comment: Try printing out swiftyJsonVar1, strjson, swiftyJsonVar

Comment: print its value "responseData.result.value" right after this line in your code if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {.

Comment: @MoayadAlkouz I tried, but return empty

Comment: @Saurabh i did but nothing change

Comment: @MRizwan33 i did that, but return empty!

Comment: @Yasmin I have pasted the code with few changes. Just try it out.

Comment: if you got my question correctly what i want you to do then probably nothing coming from Service in Arabic. Or just use break point after  
this line "if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {" and run your code it will stopes here then write in console "po responseData.result.value" after that whatever result comes print it and show us. So that we can reach exactly whats happening there.

Comment: @MRizwan33 I did your steps and when write in console "po responseData.result.value" that print nil

Comment: @MRizwan33 and for your peivuse qusetion in my JSON service nothing coming in Arabic.

Comment: @Yasmin Try out my code one more time

Comment: use postman and check is backend sending data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Content-Type header to request:

```
var requestURL = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https//:wwww.mywebsite.com")!)
requestURL.addValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Comment: there is issue : Cannot call value of non-function type 'URLRequest'

Comment: It's `requestURL.addValue("application/json; charset=utf-8"...)`

Comment: She is already getting the `json` response for english. I don't see any fix here.

Comment: This is not the answer She/He already have result in english.

Comment: I guess for Arabic the response is not in valid JSON format

Comment: @Kamran and MRizwan33 But she isn't getting the result as expected. So this is just a try out code.

Comment: Arabic text is not something that can bother response. You guess could have been a comment also. see how #Larme did.

Comment: @Kamran That's because I didn't  pasted my code properly.

Comment: Yes that was the only line you suggested. The rest of the code doesn't make any sense to be pasted here.

Comment: @Kamran Yeah I pasted the whole code for the user's convenience.

Comment: thank you for trying,  I get a result in english, the problem in Arabic response.